# How Github implemented its Pull Request feature

Tags: git, version-control, github, implementation, gitorious

I have question about GitHub — how they implemented Pull Request feature.
Git SCM itself has [git-request-pull](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-request-pull.html) commands.
According to this answer GitHub can use [git-request-pull](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-request-pull.html) and [git-format-patch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) to do this.

How they implemented this feature? And what about Gitorious and Gitlab? How they did the same?

Comment: IIRC, they are open-source. Why don't you just check it for yourself? Or ask "them" directly, I mean, whoever seems to be roughly-recently contributing to that part of Git?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They store the name of the branch from which you want to pull and generate diffs using `git diff ^target-branch pull-head`. When you accept the pull request, they simply run `git merge pull-base`.

They do not use `git request-pull`. There is even [a discussion where Linus Torwalds insults them for it](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/17#issuecomment-5654674) :)

Comment: You made my day by this link! Thanx alot!

Comment: What about Gitorious and Gitlab?

Comment: I have little experience with those, but I am pretty sure they do the same.

Comment: but with the diff, how can you know there will be merge conflicts or not?

Comment: You need to run `git merge` to find out if there are merge conflicts. I'd assume that's also very close to what they do.